# Can I collect user input with SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I need to create a "tracker" style system to collect data on complaints and where they are going and how they are handled. The system should be available in real time and across multiple sites.

Can I use SharePoint to create user friendly forms for data input? Can I then make fairly straight forward reports for them that can be generated on the fly?

Comment: Try to be more specific in your question and/or divide the questions into several questions. Here we like ONE question, not several. We're here to help if we can divide the problem further. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, you can create a tracking system that allow user to report issues also generate report in the fly (from a designer's perspective, I won't say it's user friendly.) If you can be more specific (process flow and requirement etc) about the business process, people will be able to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the out of the box 'Issue tracking' list template.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I then make fairly fraught forward reports for them that can be
> generated in the fly?

Yes, you can.

I'd say, start with SharePoint Online. You can get a free trial license [here](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/office-365-enterprise-e3-business-software) and you can start using the environment without unnecessary hassle and investment into server infrastructure.

Navigate to your site collection (it's url will be https://NAMEYouChoseFORSubscription.sharepoint.com) and create a list (Site Contents>Add an App>Custom List). In the beginning it will look pretty bleak, but you can go to the Ribbon>List Settings>scroll down to Columns and add more fields (one for every line of the user input you need to collect).
You will see that these columns are reflected in the list and in the NewForm - an input form that your users can use to enter data. The form can be additionally modified (flowers, pictures, etc.) using e.g. InfoPath.

As for generating reports - it all depends what kind of reports you want.

1. Site Settings>Audit logs
2. List ribbon> Export to Excel (if you want the content of the list)
3. List view (you can e.g. select some data fulfilling certain conditions - only complaints on OneDepartment - and save this view for others or your personal use only)
4. Change history - either via List Settings>Versioning or through site collection change log.

The list itself allows for all kinds of filtering and data selection.

For assigning the complaints you could use workflows. On creation of the complaint, the workflow would send an email to you/manager or create a task for Complaints team.

Possibilites are endless, so once try to play with it, see how much it answers your company's needs and then ask again if you find something missing.